# How to see what caused windows to kill my java app (end task dialog)?

Tags: windows, java, freeze, crash

I wrote some javafx based java app. It performed without any problem on any of my teams dev machines for 2 years. But it is installed in production on about 700 machines (with different configurations), all running windows 7 or 8 and it is randomly crashing there. Daily there are around 100 crashes cumulatively from all machines. App freezes with end task dialog shown, basically windows killing the java app. There is no error in the logs, not memory leaks, cpu is around 20% on all machines that I profiled.

It is crashing randomly, not tied to specific configuration that I can see. Tried updating java, but the crash just shows up differently (black screen + freeze instead just freezing screen).

App is playing 5-6 different screens, every screen have full screen video playing with some text animated over it. Videos are compressed to h264 with everything set to ease the load on the CPU.

On one PC I got JavaVM crash log that complained about some gstreamer.dll used by javafx.

Is there any way to debug this random behaviour which is killing the VM completely? Is there any way to see in some windows error logs why it killed the java app?

Comment: Have you looked in the event logs?

Comment: @DavidPostill yes, but I could not dig out anything. maybe I do not know how to properly dig through heaps of win event logs. I am currently monitoring HW temperatures on some of the worst machines (they are not properly cooled)

Comment: Overheating will not cause an individual app to crash. It will shutdown the whole machine.

Comment: @DavidPostill Probably, but I am out of ideas where to look